# Appending to a to-do list with jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code to append to a to-do list works in the editor in a Codecademy tutorial, but using the same code in CodePen, nothing happens when I type text into the form box and hit submit (whereas in Codecademy, the entered text is added below the form box). It's not just an issue with CodePen, either; the same thing happened after entering it into Atom. 
To see how it works you can [view my CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VXmPrO), but I'll also enter the code used below for convenience.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To Do</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>To Do</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div class="button">Add</div>
        <br>
        <div class="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    let toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    // inserts specified element as last child of target element
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Why the discrepancy? Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: Maybe you need to include `jquery`? You know that `$` stands for `jQuery` (or some other library)

Comment: jQuery wasn't included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable jQuery. Also, if you want to clear the input field after adding a new item you can do this:

```
$('input[name=checkListItem]').val('');
```

Here's a working solution!

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    let toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    console.log(toAdd);
    // inserts specified element as last child of target element
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    $('input[name=checkListItem]').val('');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: grey;
}

form {
  /* needed for the same property/value to work to display the button next to form */
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 1.6em;
  width: 15em;
}

.button {
  /* makes button display next to form */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 0 #fff;
  /* starts at top, transitions from left to right */
 background: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 color: #666;
 background-color: #c00;
 font-size: 0.7em;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 0.33em;
 /* padding is space between element's content and border. First value sets top and bottom padding; second value sets right and left */
 padding: 0.5em 0.9em;
 text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
 text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <h2>To Do</h2>
      <form name="checkListForm">
       <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
      </form>
      <div class="button">Add</div>
      <br>
      <div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: No need to include jQuery manually, CodePen can handle that.

Comment: @AndreyPetrov right, but my snippet code isn't using CodePen, and her code on CodePen was not using jQuery either

Answer (score 0):

You have to add jQuery support to your CodePen snippet. Click on "settings" in JavaScript window, then pick "jQuery" from "Quick-add" dropdown in the bottom of "Pen Settings" window.

You will have to link to jQuery dependency manually so your code can work flawless outside sandboxes like Codeacademy, CodePen, JSFiddle etc.

Here is how to use jQuery from CDN: http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn

Basically, you will end up adding something like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before the `<script src="script.js"></script>` line.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at pen.js:1
>   Blockquote

Hey, Its always advisable to look at browser console to check what the error is. 60% of your problems will be solved by just looking at console. and next 40 % be be solved by debugging the javascript code using chrome browser. This is the error that is thrown along with other few errors. It means that you have not included Jquery library in your html. Please import it using this cdn link
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
 or as mention by Andrey Petrov